# Localization using IMU and LiDAR only

Tags: ros, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am quite new to particle filters and other localization algorithms. For my project I am using an IMU and 2D LiDAR on a robot for indoor navigation. Is it possible to develop a new (or adapt existing ROS packages) to localize the robot using solely an IMU and LiDAR assuming,

1. I have a map of the environment
2. I do not have a map of the environment?

Setup - ROS Noetic + Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388913/localization-using-imu-and-lidar-only/) by [ashwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/59677/ashwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we can create tf odom (information about how far the robot has moved from where it is now) from IMU, we can use `amcl` to match it with a map and localize it.

I don't know of any existing packages, but if you have the velocity and angular velocity, you should be able to calculate the robot's movement information, but IMU is prone to noise, so you may need to devise a way to get better accuracy.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0